# Prove that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |X_n|/n \le1 $ almost surely

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ a sequence of random variables.
If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_n|>n)< \infty$

Prove that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{ |X_n|}{n} \le1 $$ almost surely

**What i have done so far:**

I thought using the Borel-Cantelli lemma could lead me somewhere, but i didn't have any luck.

From Borel-Cantelli lemma we know that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_n|>n)< \infty$ then $P(|X_n|>n)=0$

How could I proceed?
I would appreciate any help, advice. Thank you all very much in advance for your time and concern.

Comment: Hint: Borel-Cantelli lemma shows that $\Bbb{P}(|X_{n}| > n \text{ i.o.}) = 0$.

Comment: Crossposted: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/63561/2970

Comment: @cardinal so what? i can not post my question in two different sections?

Comment: @johan: [See this meta.SO answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/158524). This is the *quasi* official policy on this topic. Cheers.

Comment: didn't know that i am really sorry, but i think it is not big deal to spent your time!

Comment: @johan: It's ok. I just wanted you to be aware of the prevailing "policy". I generally believe it's good to have the content in one location since one objective is the site is to provide a long-term repository of questions and answers.  (+1 to your question, in particular for supplying your initial thoughts on the problem. Cheers.)

Comment: johan paul, Edited answer

Answer (score 4):

The first Borel-Cantelli lemma yields
$$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}|X_n|>n\right)=0. $$
As for each $n$ $$\{|X_n|>n\}\subset \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty \{|X_k|>k\}, $$
it follows that
\begin{align}
0&=\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty \{|X_k|>k\}\right) \\&=\mathbb P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty \{|X_k|>k\}  \right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty \{|X_k|>k\} \right)\\
&\geqslant\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(|X_n|>n)
\end{align}
and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(|X_n|>n)=0$. Further, $$\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty \{|X_k|>k\}\subset\{|X_n|>n\} $$
so that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} |X_n|\leqslant n\right) &= \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty\{|X_k|\leqslant k\}\right)\\
&=1 - \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty \{|X_k|>k\} \right)\\
&=1 - \mathbb P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty\{|X_k|>k\} \right)\\
&=1 - \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty\{|X_k|>k\}\right)\\
&\geqslant1 - \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(|X_n|>n)\\
&= 1,
\end{align}
which implies that
$$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{|X_n|}n\leqslant 1 \right)=1. $$

Comment: How do you know the first equation? From the contrapositive of the direct result of BCL1? Anyway answer looks good \m/

Answer (score 3):

By Borel Cantelli lemma we have that 
$$ P( \liminf_{n \to \infty} \{ |X_n| \leq n \}) = P( \{|X_n| \leq n \text{ eventually } \} )= 1$$
In words this means than almost surely, the sequence $|X_n|$ is below $n$ for all $n$ sufficently large. I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask you something more?
How can we pass from the probability to the limit suprermum of the inequality?

Comment: If $|X_n|$ can't surpass $n$ for $n$, then what happens to $\frac{|X_n|}{n}$?. Also remember that the limsup of a sequence is its largest acummulation point.

Comment: but this equality is true only if the events are independent, which in my case are not. Am I right?

Comment: We used the "original" Borel Cantelli which does not need independence of the events. The converse (i.e $\sum P(\ldots) = \infty \Rightarrow P( \ldots i.o) = 1$) requires independence. Check  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma

Answer (score -1):

Important inequalities

Williams - Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

Deduced similarly:

(iii) If $\liminf x_n > z$, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n > z)$ eventually (that is, for infinitely many n)

(iv) If $\liminf x_n < z $, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n < z)$ infinitely often (that is, for infinitely many n)

---

By BCL1, we have $P(\limsup (|X_n| > n)) = 0$

$$\to P(\liminf (|X_n| \le n)) = 1$$

$$\to P(\liminf (|X_n|/n \le 1)) = 1$$

$$\to P([\limsup |X_n|/n] \le 1)) = 1$$

The last step follows by the contrapositive of 2 (see above)